# StArea() in sqlserver is in which unit?

Tags: polygon, sql-server, area

I have a problem with saving `STArea` in sqlserver. Here is a query where I get the area of a polygon:

```
select Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((51.3386535086000000 31.7951253522000000, 51.3388695102000000 31.7952389270000000, 51.3388979249000000 31.7952464707000000, 51.3390467037000000 31.7953440361000000, 51.3392599393000000 31.7954571079000000, 51.3394563273000000 31.7955843452000000, 51.3396358676000000 31.7956905439000000, 51.3398606703000000 31.7958423402000000, 51.3399567269000000 31.7958984151000000, 51.3402088545000000 31.7960463557000000, 51.3404525165000000 31.7961833999000000, 51.3405501656000000 31.7962423246000000, 51.3405803405000000 31.7962540593000000, 51.3407558575000000 31.7963579111000000, 51.3407710288000000 31.7963713221000000, 51.3408634812000000 31.7964024190000000, 51.3410357293000000 31.7965043429000000, 51.3411784731000000 31.7965789419000000, 51.3412407506000000 31.7965510301000000, 51.3414824009000000 31.7962486111000000, 51.3417441677000000 31.7959164362000000, 51.3419324253000000 31.7956736963000000, 51.3419411425000000 31.7956510652000000, 51.3417580817000000 31.7955185473000000, 51.3413181156000000 31.7952600494000000, 51.3409249205000000 31.7950360849000000, 51.3404942583000000 31.7947866395000000, 51.3400418032000000 31.7945303209000000, 51.3396468479000000 31.7942999862000000, 51.3395502046000000 31.7943521217000000, 51.3392463606000000 31.7945348471000000, 51.3389606215000000 31.7947612423000000, 51.3386898860000000 31.7950401921000000, 51.3386374991000000 31.7951089237000000, 51.3386374153000000 31.7951182276000000, 51.3386535086000000 31.7951253522000000))',32639).MakeValid().STArea()
```

It gives me `3.49106150461542E-06`. How I can find that this area is right? In which unit is the `STArea()` measured in? And which code must I use instead 32639 for the points that came from the gps device?

**Edit,This is how I read points **

```
 var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);

            XNamespace ns = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            var values = xmlDocument.Root
                          .Descendants(ns + "trkpt")
                          .Select(x => new
                          {
                              lat = (string)x.Attribute("lat"),
                              lon = (string)x.Attribute("lon"),
                              ele = (string)x.Element(ns + "ele")

                          })
                          .ToList();
            //List<IPoint> ipoint = new List<IPoint>();
            string poinnts = "";
            foreach (var val in values)
            {
                string[] cordinates = { val.lat, val.lon, val.ele };

                poinnts += "," + val.lon.ToString() + " " + val.lat.ToString()+" " + val.ele.ToString();

            }
            poinnts=poinnts.Remove(0, 1);

            poinnts += ","+poinnts.Split(',')[0];

            GeomConverter gc = new GeomConverter();
            Polygon poly = gc.CreatePolygonFromPoints(poinnts);


            FeatureType res = poly.FeatureType;
            Fset = new DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet(res);

            Fset.Projection = DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(Properties.Settings.Default.UTMCode);

            Fset.AddFeature(poly);
            area = poly.Area;
            length = poly.Length;
            this.status = true;

            return Fset;


        }
```

Here Is `Create PolygonFromPoint()`

```
    public Polygon CreatePolygonFromPoints(string feature)
    {


        string[] coordinates = feature.Split(',');


        double[] xy = new double[coordinates.Length*2];
        double[] z = new double[coordinates.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] cord = coordinates[i].Split(' ');
            double lon = double.Parse(cord[0]);
            double lat = double.Parse(cord[1]);
            double ele = double.Parse(cord[1]);

            xy[i*2] = lon;
            xy[i * 2 + 1] = lat;
            z[i] = ele;
        }

        ProjectionInfo pStart = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;


        ProjectionInfo pEnd = KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.UtmWgs1984.WGS1984UTMZone39N;


        Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, pStart, pEnd, 0, coordinates.Length);


        List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate> co = new List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate>();
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Length; i++)
        {
            co.Add(new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate(xy[i*2],xy[i*2+1],z[i]));
        }

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon(co);
        return polygon;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area is certainly wrong because your data is in decimal degrees and the "geometry" data type treats it as though it were planar with units of equal distance.  An "area" in degree units is meaningless.  Degrees longitude cover shorter distances the farther you get from the equator.

For data in degrees you can use the "geography" data type which does geodetic computations for things such as distance or area and returns results in meters.

Most GPS devices use WGS 84 for which the code is 4326.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, "geometry" measurement functions return in whatever units the data are in.

Comment: Thanks for your help.you mean If I change my data type to geography it works fine?So the polygon that is created is wrong too?Can you give me an example how to work with this gps data?

Comment: If you change the datatype to geography, SRID 4326, your area and distance computations should be correct (in square meters/meters).

Comment: The polygon isn't wrong, it's simply that as a geometry it's treated as if the coordinate system is laid out on a flat surface rather than on a spheroid.  If you were using a projected coordinate system to store your data, you'd need to use geometry because geography does not accept SRIDs that represent projections.

Comment: The other issue that sometimes gets people when first working with this type of data is that coordinates are x, y, that is longitude, latitude.  If your polygon is in Iran you entered it correctly.  If its in the Ukraine you got it backwards.

Comment: I don't have an example because I generally use the geometry data type, store my data in projected coordinate systems, and correct measurements for projection distortion (which works better for small areas than for huge ones).  But for your scenario, from what I know of it from your post, I'd use geography.

Comment: Dear Russell thanks very much for your great information.Yes the place that I work is in Iran,I have an Idea.I converted points to set of cordinates and projected them to zone 39n then I created a polygon using dotspatial liberary and calculated area using that polygon.Than I get WTK from that polygon and saved it as a geometry type in database.Is this scenario wrong?I mean does this makes any wrong placement of features or changes in area or sth like that?

Comment: I updated my code with new method

Comment: You should be aware that ANY projected coordinate system will distort at least one of: area, distance, shape.  The details of what and of how to correct vary by projection.  If you need highly accurate measurements you should stick to degrees and use geography so that computations are based on a spheroid surface.

Comment: In my work I create web maps overlaid on Bing or similar tiles, so I store the data in the Spherical Mercator projection used by Bing, OpenStreetMaps, etc.  I'm more concerned with fast rendering than perfect measurements.  I can correct measurements for small areas- a US football field measures perfectly- but over areas with significant curvature, such as a polygon of the entire US, the corrections are imperfect.

Comment: as ISC Thanks a lot for your helps.I need a normal accuracy so I think it does not have any problem with little distort.Can I match shaped created by this way on open street or bing or google map?

Comment: You will need your data to be in Spherical Mercator (SRID = 3857) to overlay onto Bing.  Spherical Mercator significantly distorts area and distance particularly at greater latitudes.  Multiply distance by the cosine of the latitude to correct it.